# Notepad++ using wrong highlight for .txt, .conf, .log file types

Tags: syntax, notepad++, highlight, txt

Hello and happy holidays,

I'm running Notepad++ 8.6 (build time: Nov 23 2023 - 16:58:44) on Windows 10 Pro for work

Since that update, when I open a .txt, .log or .conf file by double-clicking it in file explorer it opens with orange highlight all over the place as you can see in the image below (filename test.txt)

[image: Sample of .txt highlight]

Last time this happened it was because of the json extension. This time I have removed the extension and I am still getting this issue

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your current document language might be JSON and it shows a JSON ERROR file.
To fix it go Notepad++ Settings->Style Configuration->Language:JSON->Style:ERROR.
I hope it helps!

Comment: hi K123, thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly I need to change the JSON ERROR style to the same as the default to avoid this error?

Comment: Ok I did change the settings and now it's a different colour. I also noticed that when I open the .txt file the "None (normal text)" language is not selected, how can I fix that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).